# Showing that $\mathbb{Z^*_{p^k}}$ is cyclic proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It can be shown by induction on $k$ that  in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$, $p+1$ has multiplicative order $p^{k-1}$. We know that $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$  is cyclic since it's the multiplicative group of a finite field so it has a generator $r$ which has order $p-1$.
The order of $r$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ must divide the order of $r$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ so $p-1\mid o(r)$ so there is an element of order $p-1$ in $\langle r\rangle$ and therefore in  $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$. Since we are in an abelian group and there exists an element of order $p-1$ and an element of order $p^{k-1}$ there must be an element of order $(p-1)p^{k-1}$ which is the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}^*_{p^k}$. Therefore it must be cyclic. Is this correct?

Edit: $p$ is a prime different from $2$.

Comment: The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic if $p$ is odd. But it is not for example for $p^k = 8$.

Comment: @spin my bad I will correct my post

Comment: The proof seems correct. There is just a typo, "and element of order $p^{k-1}$ there must be an element of order $(p-1)p^{k-1}$"

Comment: @JulianMejia thank you fixed

Comment: a bit overkill but try with Carmichael function